# How to set date in weekdays

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have date from 01/01/1859 to up till date of today.

I have some sessions in these dates of some subjects.

Now I have to create a time table.

In one day there are five sessions like Monday have five slots, slot 1 slot 2 slot 3 slot 4 slot 5.

I have to make a query that if sessions lie on the Wednesday, session should lie in the Wednesday column. And particular slot of that Wednesday which i give to session.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expected results?

Comment: I can not post image to you so that i can show you my results can you send me email so i can mail you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: 
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())

Answer (score 1):

**SQL Server**

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) = 4 -- Wednesday
```

`DATEPART` return an integer which represent the following:

1. Sunday
2. Monday
3. Tuesday
4. Wednesday
5. Thursday
6. Friday
7. Saturday

**C#**

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Today;
bool IsWednesday = (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday);
```